# TDD - Why does this Assert.AreSame pass?

Tags: c#, tdd, mstest, assert

I have a test method...

```
[TestMethod]
public void MainViewModel_PropertiesReflectDataEntityProperties()
{
    // Arrange
    var facilityDataEntity = MockRepository.GenerateStub<FacilityDataEntity>();
    var shopOrderDataEntity = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ShopOrderDataEntity>();

    // Act
    MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(facilityDataEntity, shopOrderDataEntity);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreSame(facilityDataEntity.Value, mainViewModel.FacilityValue);
}
```

... and the test passes. However, I have not implemented the mapping of the DataEntity's properties to the MainViewModel's properties yet! How can this be? I thought AreSame checks whether two references point to the same instance.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly FacilityDataEntity facilityDataEntity;
    private readonly ShopOrderDataEntity shopOrderDataEntity;

    public MainViewModel(FacilityDataEntity facilityDataEntity)
    {
        this.facilityDataEntity = facilityDataEntity;
    }

    public MainViewModel(FacilityDataEntity facilityDataEntity, ShopOrderDataEntity shopOrderDataEntity)
    {
        this.facilityDataEntity = facilityDataEntity;
        this.shopOrderDataEntity = shopOrderDataEntity;
    }

    public ShopOrderDataEntity ShopOrderDataEntity
    {
        get { return shopOrderDataEntity; }
    }

    public FacilityDataEntity FacilityDataEntity
    {
        get { return facilityDataEntity; }
    } 

    public int ShopOrder { get; set; }

    public decimal RequiredQuantity { get; set; }

    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public string FacilityValue { get; set; }

    public string FacilityLabel { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<MainViewModel> TranslateDataEntityList(IEnumerable<FacilityDataEntity> facilityDataEntityList)
    {
        foreach (FacilityDataEntity facilityDataEntity in facilityDataEntityList)
        {
            yield return new MainViewModel(facilityDataEntity);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MainViewModel> TranslateDataEntityList(FacilityDataEntity facilityDataEntity, IEnumerable<ShopOrderDataEntity> shopOrderDataEntityList)
    {
        foreach (ShopOrderDataEntity shopOrderDataEntity in shopOrderDataEntityList)
        {
            yield return new MainViewModel(facilityDataEntity, shopOrderDataEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you debug the values of `facilityDataEntity.Value` and  `mainViewModel.FacilityValue`

Comment: The same question goes for Assert.ReferenceEquals

Comment: Presumably, they're both `null` at this point.

Comment: I have debugged the test, and yes, they are both null, but I'm not doing an AreEqual, so how can they be the same instance? Or does them being null MAKE them the same instance, or instance-less or something?

Comment: They're not the same instance. They're the same lack of an instance.

Comment: Just to clarify how to think about null in C#: It's just another value, meaning null == null. This is quite different from null i relational databases, where null is not a value but means "unknown", which implies very different logic than in C#. For example, in DB null = null evaluates to null but is coerced to false where a boolean value is required, e.g. in a where clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underneath it all, these tests are just using [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx):

> **true** if *objA* is the same instance as *objB* or if both are **null**; otherwise, **false**.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is happening because they are both `null`.

Answer (score 2):

in this case, I'd say its comparing null with null, which are the same.